# <a href> emailing from inside an html file

Tags: html, css, email

I am doing a basic html page, using a free web template that I found online. In the "contact" section, I would like to set it up such that

```
<a href= "mailto:me@gmail.com"> Myself </a>
```

allows emailing to myself from the page directly. However, when I click on the link, nothing comes up, no emailing program... nothing. Could it have something to do with the fact that I got a free web template with it's own included css file, which could be overriding whatever emailing functionality the html might provide? This seems relatively simple, but for whatever reason nothing happens when I click the email link.

Comment: I am afraid no full template no help :-( And I bet you have made some typo somewhere

Comment: oh man.... that could take a while to throw on here... if it helps the <a href> is inside a <li> element, which is being formatted by the css file.

Comment: Do you have any emailing program installed?

Comment: CSS can't disable the functionality of mailto, I know that.

Comment: @Zack make sure there is no typo.

Comment: It could be preventing you from clicking the link though. Try this. Take out the mailto and make ti go to google.com or something, then try to click it, does it take you there?

Comment: @Musa, what do you mean? Shouldn't there be one by default? How does mailto work?

Comment: @JacksonGariety you can cover actual anchor with some div etc. ;)

Comment: @Musa has a good answer. If you have no mail program on your computer, the mailto link would have no app to open.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski That's still not disabling the functionality of mailto which is built into the browser.

Comment: I tried making it www.google.com and got a 404 not found error....

Comment: @Zack you missed http:// in link, but good news is anchor is working, bad news you have bad configured browser / no mail app

Comment: when I tried to make it google, this happened 
http://mysite.com/www.google.com

Comment: @Zack Then CSS isn't preventing you from clicking the link. You probably just don't have an email client on your computer. Download thunderbird and see if it launches when you click the link/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "mailto:" function opens a new e-mail in your default e-mail client. Since it looks like you are using GMail, then I am just guessing (correct me if I'm wrong) but you are using the web interface to compose and check you gmail messages and don't have a default email client set up. Either setup your default client (Outlook, Thunderbird, Mail, etc) OR if you are using Chrome web browser you can set it as your default gmail client ([Making Gmail your default mail application](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966)).

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe it was a problem of not having http:// as well as not having an emailing client configured. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Look which Standard-Email-Client you are using. In Firefox: Options > Applications > Filter > Search for "mailto". I guess the Client-list is empty or not set.

CSS can't block mailto, but JS can.

Try to put your code in a simmple blank HTML file and click the link:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <a href= "mailto:me@gmail.com"> Myself </a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think his point of doing this was to load a page with no javascript on it. If it didn't work when you made that html file and clicked, it means the JS isn't blocking it either.

Answer (score 0):

You need an email client that processes the **URL:Mailto** filetype.
Without a proper default email client nothing ever happens when the link gets clicked.

Btw. mailto usage can be extended to include a draft and receivers in the created email.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com
    ?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com, another@thatsite.com, me@mysite.com
       &bcc=lastperson@theirsite.com
           &subject=Big%20News&body=Body-goes-here">mail now</a>
```